# How to send environment variables to Jest CLI?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, jestjs

I have a script that runs a Jest test for me, and I want to set an environment variable before running it, something like this:

**my_test_script.sh**

```
IMPORTANT_ENV_VAR=value_that_matters
./node_modules/.bin/jest --useStderr ./__tests__/my.test.js
```

However, inside "my.test.js" the `IMPORTANT_ENV_VAR` is not set when I run my test like this.

How do I pass the environment variable into the Jest CLI ?

Answer (score 2):

What i do to solve the problem is ugly, but works.

I'm searching for a better solution (Simply set a Environment Variable by cli), not able to find it.

i create a js file that set the environment variable and i load that file passing it to the setupFile cli command. for example

```
jest --setupFile=setter.js
```

and setter.js contains

```
process.env.A = "B"
```

so, before running each test, i can read the process.env.A variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
  }
}
```

Its purpose is *exactly* to pass environment variables to an npm script in a cross-platform way.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @Andrea Bisello's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889022/3773048), you can load the environment variables from a plain JavaScript file. This is the key take-away.

So, in my environment, I already had a `jest.config.ts`. Since I was already using a `.env` file for defining my environment variables (located at the root of my project), I just needed a way to load them when running jest from a CLI at the root of my project.

Doing that is very simple; just add this to the `jest.config.ts` or `jest.config.js`:

```js
// jest.config.{ts,js}
const { config } = require('dotenv');

config();
```

Then, from the root of your repo, you can do something like:

```sh
npx jest
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's hard to set environment variables in a platform-independent way under npm/package.json, and because jest --setupFiles, while in the usage, isn't in the docs and doesn't seem to work (24.9), jest REALLY DOES need a --envVar option to support environmental overrides external to package.json (like dev/production).

Answer (score -1):

Whoops!
Not a Jest problem, I just needed to **`export`** in the shell script :

```
export IMPORTANT_ENV_VAR=value_that_matters
./node_modules/.bin/jest --useStderr ./__tests__/my.test.js
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using npm, you can add this to your package.json to define environment variables in the testing env.

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "ENVVAR1": true,
    "ENVVAR2": "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for setting global variables, not environment variables.